# Stop using DefaultIterableDiffer, KeyValueDiffers#factories, or IterableDiffers#factories

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular2-routing, angular5

-I am trying to do angular upgrade from angular 2 to angular 5
- I followed the instructions in the below link
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/
**- I am trying to do this step Stop using  IterableDiffers#factories**
- not sure with what I should replace IterableDiffe.
- right now I have commented those lines and ran the application...other components working fine.
- providing my code snippet below.

```
/*
 * Angular 2 Dropdown Sports for Bootstrap
 * Current version: 0.2.0
 * 
 * Simon Lindh
 * https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-Sports
 */
import { NgModule, Component, Pipe, OnInit, DoCheck, HostListener, Input, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

//import { NgModule, Component, Pipe, OnInit, DoCheck, HostListener, Input, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef, IterableDiffers } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import {saveService} from '../../services/saveService';


const Sports_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => SportsDropdown),
    multi: true
};

export interface ISportsOption {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface ISportsSettings {
    pullRight?: boolean;
    enableSearch?: boolean;
    checkedStyle?: 'checkboxes' | 'glyphicon';
    buttonClasses?: string;
    selectionLimit?: number;
    closeOnSelect?: boolean;
    showCheckAll?: boolean;
    showUncheckAll?: boolean;
    dynamicTitleMaxItems?: number;
    maxHeight?: string;
    isAll?: boolean;
}

export interface ISportsTexts {
    checkAll?: string;
    uncheckAll?: string;
    checked?: string;
    checkedPlural?: string;
    searchPlaceholder?: string;
    defaultTitle?: string;
}

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SportsSearchFilter {
    transform(options: Array<ISportsOption>, args: string): Array<ISportsOption> {
        return options.filter((option: ISportsOption) => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf((args || '').toLowerCase()) > -1);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'ss-Sports-dropdown',
    providers: [Sports_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    styles: [`
        a { outline: none !important; }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 350px;" class="dropdown-toggle" [ngClass]="settings.buttonClasses" (click)="toggleDropdown()">{{ title }}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul *ngIf="isVisible" class="dropdown-menu" [class.pull-right]="settings.pullRight" [style.max-height]="settings.maxHeight" style="display: block; height: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
                <li style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;" *ngIf="settings.enableSearch">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ texts.searchPlaceholder }}" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3" [(ngModel)]="searchFilterText">
                        <span class="input-group-btn" *ngIf="searchFilterText.length > 0">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="clearSearch()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="divider" *ngIf="settings.enableSearch"></li>
                <li *ngIf="!isAllSelected() && settings.isAll">
                    <a href="javascript:;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" (click)="checkAll()">

                        {{ texts.checkAll }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="isAllSelected() && settings.isAll">
                    <a href="javascript:;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" (click)="uncheckAll()">
                        <span  style="width: 16px;" class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-ok]="isAllSelected()"></span>
                        {{ texts.checkAll }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="(settings.showCheckAll || settings.showUncheckAll) && settings.isAll" class="divider"></li>
                <li *ngFor="let option of options | searchFilter:searchFilterText">
                    <a href="javascript:;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" (click)="setSelected($event, option)">
                        <input *ngIf="settings.checkedStyle == 'checkboxes'" type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(option)" />
                        <span *ngIf="settings.checkedStyle == 'glyphicon'" style="width: 16px;" class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-ok]="isSelected(option)"></span>
                        {{ option.name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})
export class SportsDropdown implements OnInit, DoCheck, ControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() options: Array<ISportsOption>;
    @Input() settings: ISportsSettings;
    @Input() texts: ISportsTexts;
    @Output() selectionLimitReached = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() modelChangeDetected = new EventEmitter();
    @HostListener('document: click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick(target) {
        let parentFound = false;
        while (target !== null && !parentFound) {
            if (target === this.element.nativeElement) {
                parentFound = true;
            }
            target = target.parentElement;
        }
        if (!parentFound) {
            this.isVisible = false;
        }
    }

    protected onModelChange: Function = (_: any) => {};
    protected onModelTouched: Function = () => {};
    protected model: number[];
    protected title: string;
    //protected differ: any;
    protected numSelected: number = 0;
    protected isVisible: boolean = false;
    protected searchFilterText: string = '';
    protected defaultSettings: ISportsSettings = {
        pullRight: false,
        enableSearch: false,
        checkedStyle: 'checkboxes',
        buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default',
        selectionLimit: 0,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        showCheckAll: false,
        showUncheckAll: false,
        dynamicTitleMaxItems: 1,
        maxHeight: '300px',
        isAll: true
    };
    protected defaultTexts: ISportsTexts = {
        checkAll: 'All',
        uncheckAll: 'Uncheck all',
        checked: 'checked',
        checkedPlural: 'checked',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
        defaultTitle: 'Select',
    };

    // constructor(
    //     protected element: ElementRef,
    //     protected differs: IterableDiffers,
    //     public saveService: saveService
    // ) {
    //     this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
    // }

    constructor(
        protected element: ElementRef,
        public saveService: saveService
    ) {
       // this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.settings = Object.assign(this.defaultSettings, this.settings);
        this.texts = Object.assign(this.defaultTexts, this.texts);              
    }

    writeValue(value: any) : void {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            this.model = value;
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = fn;
    }

    // ngDoCheck() {
    //     let changes = this.differ.diff(this.model);
    //     if (changes) {
    //         this.updateNumSelected();
    //         if(this.options && this.options.length > 0 && this.options[0]["countryName"]) {
    //             this.updateTitle(true);
    //         }
    //         else{
    //             this.updateTitle(false);
    //         }
    //     }
    // }

    clearSearch() {
        this.searchFilterText = '';
    }

    toggleDropdown() {
        this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    }

    isSelected(option: ISportsOption): boolean {
        return this.model && this.model.indexOf(option.id) > -1;
    }

    isAllSelected(): boolean {
        if(this.model.length == this.options.length){            
            return true;
        }
        else {            
            return false;

        }
    }

    setSelected(event: Event, option: ISportsOption) {
            if(option["countryName"]){
                if(this.model.length == 3 && this.model.indexOf(option.id) == -1) {
                    this.selectionLimitReached.emit(this.model.length);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    let saveBtnEnable = {};
                    saveBtnEnable["enableBtn"] = true;
                    this.saveService.setSaveBtnEnable(saveBtnEnable);
                }
            }

            var index = this.model.indexOf(option.id);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.model.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                if (this.settings.selectionLimit === 0 || this.model.length < this.settings.selectionLimit) {
                    this.model.push(option.id);
                } else {
                    this.selectionLimitReached.emit(this.model.length);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (this.settings.closeOnSelect) {
                this.toggleDropdown();
            }
            this.onModelChange(this.model);
            this.modelChangeDetected.emit(true);

    }

    updateNumSelected() {
        this.numSelected = this.model && this.model.length || 0;
    }

    updateTitle(replaceTitleBySelectedOption : boolean) {
        if (this.numSelected === 0) {
            this.title = this.texts.defaultTitle;
        } else if (this.settings.dynamicTitleMaxItems >= this.numSelected) {
            if(replaceTitleBySelectedOption) {
                if(this.model.indexOf(213) != -1) {
                   this.model = [];
                   this.model.push(213); 
                }
            }
            this.title = this.options
            .filter((option: ISportsOption) => this.model && this.model.indexOf(option.id) > -1)
            .map((option: ISportsOption) => option.name)
            .join(', ');

        } else {
            this.title = this.numSelected + ' ' + (this.numSelected === 1 ? this.texts.checked : this.texts.checkedPlural);
        }
    }

    checkAll() {        
        this.model = this.options.map(option => option.id);
        this.onModelChange(this.model);
    }

    uncheckAll() {
      this.model = [];
            this.onModelChange(this.model);
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    exports: [SportsDropdown,SportsSearchFilter],
    declarations: [SportsDropdown, SportsSearchFilter],
})
export class SportsDropdownModule { }
‌
```

Comment: could u found out the answer for that?

Comment: @mariomol no :(